How to use a custom class for the Log facade in Laravel 11
In a Laravel application every logged message must include a specific ID to identify the situation.
A custom logger extends the Log facade and implements the log methods to accept a custom object. It calls the parent class with the correct message and context.
The problem is that the standard Laravel logger is called, not the configured custom logger.
The logger is registered in a provider:
public function register (
): void {
    // Use the custom logger.
    AliasLoader::getInstance()->alias('Log', MyLogger::class);
}

When dumping all aliases with AliasLoader::getInstance()->getAliases() just before calling Log::error() I see my logger is registered:

[Log] => application\logging\MyLogger

I expect the error() method on MyLogger to be called, but instead the standard Laravel Log implementation is still used.
I have tried both Log and log as alias in the registration.
What should be changed to have Laravel use the custom Logger?
